# How can I compare real data in db and ideal ones?

Tags: python, django

I wanna test,and compare top 3 real data in db and ideal ones.
I wrote in test.py like

```
from django.test import TestCase
from app.models import User


# Create your tests here.
class UserModelTests(TestCase):
    def test_is_empty(self):
        saved_user = User.objects.first(3)
        self.assertEqual(saved_user, XXXX)
```

saved_user has `'name': Tom,'user_id': 1,'nationarity': America, 'dormitory':'A', 'group': 3     'name': Bob,'user_id': 2,'nationarity': China, 'dormitory':'B', 'group': 4 ・・・・`,so I wanna compare Tom&1&America&A&3 are typed　by myself and real db data.I really cannot understand how to write in place of XXX.Data I wanna compare is 4 kinds I confused.How should I write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django Model instances compare on primary key so testing against a `User` instance will not work here. The simplest solution here is to use `Queryset.values(...)` to retrieve raw records as dicts and compare against dicts.

Also, `User.objects.first(3)` just won't work (will raise a `TypeError`) - `Queryset.first()` takes no argument and return a single model instance. To get the first three records only (based on the model's default ordering) you have to slice your queryset, ie `User.objects.all()[:3]`.

IOW you want:

```
users = list(User.object.values()[:3])
expected = [
  {'name': 'Tom','user_id': 1,'nationarity': 'America'}, # etc
  {'name': 'Bob','user_id': 2,'nationarity': 'China', # etc
  # etc
  ]
self.assertEqual(expected, users)
```